# Link to top of the page in HTML whilst not refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a site where at the bottom of the page there is a link which displays a div in the centre of the page using JQuery...

so when you click the link you stay on the same page, the entire page fades out however this div (which contains the terms of use for the business and website) fades in... I want this div to stay dead centre of the browser (which it curently does) but because the page is long enough for you to need to scroll the div is not centralised and you must then scroll up again to view it (because the said link is at the bottom in the footer), how would I create a link to the top of the page which will not refresh the said page!

Thanks for the help... I have tried to make sense but I feel I have slightly complicated  simple question.

[=

Comment: Mind posting your version of the code?

Comment: maybe use AJAX to get the new page contents (if I understood correctly your question)

Comment: Hm... now I re-read the question I become confused. Yes, post the code please, or a link to your website.

Comment: what code would you need to see, a lot of it is very long! I have php/html page with basic page layout... one div in the centre which in css display: none;. In the code this div sits outside of the body, so when the link is clicked at the bottom of the page the body fades out and the div displayed in centre fades in.... my j query is simple function()click and ()fade(slow, 0.25) and ()fadeIn(slow)

Comment: Thanks guys, I was under the impression that using the anchor tag reloads the page and displays the page from the top of that anchor tag... but I was wrong... I think I made this question far too complicated! Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with anchor names.

See this JsFiddle example (scroll to the bottom and click the link):

http://jsfiddle.net/RahnR/2/

Comment: I agree... this is probably your best bet... back to basics.  Have you tried this?  Unless I am reading the question wrong, I'd try this method. An anchor tag won't reload anything unless the anchor link is to an anchor a separate page.

Comment: why is it always the most sipmple answer that makes you feel stupid for not thinking of! always the way (with me)! Thank you

Comment: Anchor names are deprecated. Use an `id`.

Comment: @NotJay thank you! yes you did understand the question, I made it far more difficult then needs be and though anchor tags href would reload the page but diplay at that point... but I was wrong! thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need an anchor with a name (which is deprecated anyway). Just use

```
<a href="#">To top</a>
```

Comment: Wont this refresh the page thus losing my displayed div from the jquery!

Answer (score 1):

An internal HTML anchor link ala;

```
<a name="A"></a>

<a href="#A">Go to A</a>
```

Just place the first line at the top somewhere. Alternatively if the scrollbar is still there, it might look a bit off. You could always remove the content or disable it which should also remove the scroll bar. If the user clicks off or closes the div, the content could be re-loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use this $("body").scrollTop(0);

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/dcE94/embedded/result/

works a little better than anchors